# Append input form on change returns default value

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a radio box that on change appends an input field. But input value remains always as 1000 even if type something in the appended input box. Please help, I have been struggling with this for the past two hours.

```
$('.input-amount').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === "others") {
                var htmlInput = `<input type="number" class="form-control number-as" value="1000">`;
                $('.value-amount span').text('');
                $('.value-amount span').append(htmlInput);
            }

  });
```

on below button click, I want to load the number typed in the input field but it loads default 1000 always

```
  $('#srppaymenetbutton1').on('click', function(){

    $(this).append('<div class="loader">Loading...</div>');
    var amount = $('.input-amount:checked').val();
    if (amount === "others") {
        amount = $(document).find('.number-as').val();
    }

    alert(amount);
   .........
```

Comment: Unable to replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/fm1ud5ra/. Admittedly I made some assumptions about your HTML based on the JS methods used. Please edit the question to include a working example of the issue.

Comment: Agreed with @RoryMcCrossan  as code looking fine .........

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ah, I am having the structure as yours. It is working for you but not to me :|

Comment: @pencil  create a working code example of your problem

Comment: Also check the console in devtools for errors

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Strangely no error. Thanks for confirming that I have not made an error in coding. Possibly something else is interfering. Let me try changing the structure

Comment: @pencil can you please paste your HTML and js, if possible,

Comment: @BikiMaharjan I have the same structure as posted by Rory https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/fm1ud5ra/ my code is having 4000+ lines. It will make it difficult if I post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global scope variable to store the latest values inserted. here i have used input_amount

```js
var input_amount = 1000
$('.input-amount').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === "others") {
    $('.value-amount span').html(`<input type="number" class="form-control number-as" value="${input_amount}">`);
    listenValueChange();
  }
});

function listenValueChange() {
  $(".number-as").change(function() {
    input_amount = $(this).val()
  })
}

$('#srppaymenetbutton1').on('click', function() {
  //$(this).append('<div class="loader">Loading...</div>');
  var amount = $('.input-amount:checked').val();
  if (amount === "others") {
    amount = $(document).find('.number-as').val();
  }

  console.log(amount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="input-amount" name="amt" value="foo">foo
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="input-amount" name="amt" value="bar">bar
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="input-amount" name="amt" value="others">others
</label>

<div class="value-amount">
  <span></span>
</div>

<button id="srppaymenetbutton1">Payment</button>
```